# Смежные PictureBox'ы

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

Всем привет зашел задать вопрос. как сделать, что бы изображение передавалось Drag&Drop'oм только в смежные PB'ы. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
   public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }
    private void PB1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        PictureBox pb1 = (PictureBox)sender;
        pb1.Select();
        pb1.DoDragDrop(pb1.Image, DragDropEffects.Move);
    }
    private void PB1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Bitmap))
        {
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;

        }
        else
        {
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
        }
    }
    private void PB1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        PictureBox pb = (PictureBox)sender;
        pb.Image=(Bitmap)e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap);
    }
```

Comment: Я так понимаю что иконки с цифрами это User Control -ы ? Как сейчас реализован DragDrop ?

Comment: @Сергей При старте формы свойство AllowDrop для всех элементов приходит к true.